# C bitwise AND gives different result with -O0 and -O2

Tags: c, gcc

I'm working on a PC emulator using both Bochs and DOSBox as references.

When emulating the "NEG Ed" instruction (two's complement negation of a doubleword) I'm getting different results if I compile with `-O0` rather than `-O2`.

This is a test program with just the relevant bits:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    uint32_t value = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 16);
    uint32_t negation = -(int32_t)(value);
    bool sign = negation & 0x80000000;

    printf("value=%X, negation=%X, sign=%X\n", value, negation, sign);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The `-(int32_t)(value);` part is taken from Bochs' `NEG_EdM()` function; for the equivalent operation DOSBox doesn't cast to signed int.

If you compile this program with GCC 10 using the `-O2` option and use the hexadecimal value `0x80000000` as input, you'll get a wrong result for `sign`:

`value=80000000, negation=80000000, sign=0`

When compiled with `-O0` the result is correct:

`value=80000000, negation=80000000, sign=1`

Is this undefined behaviour?

As far as I know casting to/from signed and unsigned integers is well defined, as is bitwise & on unsigned values.

Comment: Have you tried another compiler?

Comment: @DaBler it is UB

Comment: Read more about UBs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Comment: This isn't valid C because you use bool, but without including stdbool.h.

Comment: He had to include it as otherwise it will not copmile at all https://godbolt.org/z/e4ET66. He simply did not copy-paste the whole code

Comment: This is a good question, but the title should be modified to more accurately reflect it.   The question is about UB, and that should explicitly appear in the title.  Otherwise, the reader of the title will simply assume "that's UB" and not bother reading the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Source of Undefined Behavior

The key part of the problem is in the negation of `-(int32_t)value`.<sup>1</sup>

At this point, `value` is 80000000<sub>16</sub> (2<sup>31</sup>). Since that is not representable in `int32_t`, the conversion is governed by C 2018 6.3.1.3 3, which says the behavior is implementation-defined. [GCC 10.2 defines it to wrap modulo 2<sup>*N*</sup>, where the destination width is *N* bits.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation) Wrapping 80000000<sub>16</sub> to `int32_t` modulo 2<sup>32</sup> produces −80000000<sub>16</sub>.

Then the negation operator, `-`, is applied. The mathematical negation of −80000000<sub>16</sub> is of course 80000000<sub>16</sub>, but this is not representable in `int32_t`.<sup>2</sup> The behavior is governed by C 2018 6.5 5:

> If an *exceptional condition* occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined.

Thus, the negation has undefined behavior. When `-O0` is used, the compiler generates simple direct code. [Godbolt shows it generates a negate instruction](https://godbolt.org/z/TaqfjM) that wraps, producing the output 80000000<sub>16</sub> for the input bits 80000000<sub>16</sub> (which would represent −80000000<sub>16</sub> as a signed 32-bit integer). When `-O2` is used, the compiler performs complicated analysis and transformation of the program, and the lack of defined behavior leaves the compiler free to produce any result. Indeed, [Godbolt shows the negate instruction is absent](https://godbolt.org/z/Eefhhd). Effectively, the compiler “knows” that negating an `int32_t` value can never produce a result with the 2<sup>31</sup> bit set in a program with defined behavior.

### Discussion of Optimization

Consider that the range of values representable in `int32_t` is −2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>−1. The mathematical negations of these are −(2<sup>31</sup>−1) to 2<sup>31</sup>. However, 2<sup>31</sup> overflows, resulting in an exceptional condition. The range of results that do not overflow is −(2<sup>31</sup>−1) to 2<sup>31</sup>−1. Therefore, in a program with defined behavior, only these results occur, and therefore the compiler may optimize as if only these results occur. In none of these results is the 2<sup>31</sup> bit set. Therefore, in a program with defined behavior, `negation & 0x80000000` is always zero, and the compiler may generate code based on this.

### Fix

It appears you want a test for whether the sign bit would be set in an `int32_t` that is negated using two’s complement, that is, wrapping the result modulo 2<sup>32</sup>. For this, unsigned arithmetic can be used. If `x` is either an `int32_t` value or a `uint32_t` containing the bits that would represent such a value, then the sign bit of the negated value may be obtained with either of:

```
bool sign = - (uint32_t) x & 0x80000000u;
bool sign = - (uint32_t) x >> 31;
```

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> We deduce `long` is wider than 32 bits. Were it not, `strtol("0x80000000", NULL, 16)` would return `LONG_MAX`, per C 2018 7.22.1.4 8. That would be representable in `uint32_t` and `int32_t`, so `value` would be initialized to `LONG_MAX`, converting to `int32_t` would keep that value, `negation` would be −`LONG_MAX`, and `sign` would be zero in both the optimized and unoptimized versions of the program.

<sup>2</sup> If `int32_t` were narrower than `int`, the operand would be promoted to `int` before the negation, and the mathematical result would be representable. That is not the case with the GCC version and options you used, which we can deduce from the observed results.

Comment: I guess Bochs still works because of the way it computes the x86 SF flag. Probably the compiler doesn't have the same optimizazion opportunities.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your code:

- the value returned by `strtol("0x80000000", NULL, 16)` depends on the range of type `long`: if type `long` has 32 bits, the returned value should be `LONG_MAX`, which is `2147483647`, whereas if `long` is larger, `2147483648` will be returned. Converting these values to `uint32_t` does not change the value as both as within the range of `uint32_t`. Type `long` on your system seems to have 64 bits. You could avoid this implementation defined behavior using `strtoul()` instead of `strtol()`.
- there is no need for the intermediary cast to `(int32_t)`: negating the unsigned value is well defined and `-0x80000000` has the value `0x80000000` for type `uint32_t`.
- furthermore, this conversion is counterproductive and the likely cause of the observed behavior as negating the value `INT32_MIN` has undefined behavior because of signed arithmetic overflow. With optimisations enabled, the compiler determines that you are extracting the sign as if by `bool sign = -(int32_t)value < 0` and simplifies this expression as `bool sign = (int32_t)value > 0`, which is correct for all values except `INT32_MIN` for which the compiler considers any behavior to be OK, since the behavior is undefined anyway. You can check the code on [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/cWeM8o).
- you use type `bool` without including `<stdbool.h>`: the program should not compile. Is this a copy/paste error or do you compile as c++? The C99 `_Bool` semantics add an implicit test in the intialization statement, but it would be better to make it explicit and write:

  ```
  bool sign = (negation & 0x80000000) != 0;
  ```
- finally, you pass `uint32_t` values to `printf` for `%X` conversion specifiers. This is incorrect if the type `int` has fewer than 32 bits on your platform. Use the macros from `<inttypes.h>`.

Try this modified version:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    uint32_t value = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 16);
    uint32_t negation = -value;
    bool sign = (negation & 0x80000000) != 0;

    printf("value=%"PRIX32", negation=%"PRIX32", sign=%d\n", value, negation, sign);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Your unfortunate experience is rooted in the undefined behavior of signed arithmetic overflow. Compilers can take advantage of undefined behavior to implement advanced optimisations such as removing the end test in `for (int i = 0; i > 0; i++)` as well as more obvious yet non-trivial ones such as converting `void f(int i) { int j = i * 2 / 2; ...` to `int j = i;` which may exhibit different behavior for values exceeding `0x3fffffff`.

Other languages (ie: java) try and remove undefined behavior and fully specify two's complement implementation and behavior, hence will not perform these optimisations.

The Standard C language committee seems to favor more optimisations at the cost of some surprises in border cases, which may be very difficult to spot and address. Your example is a perfect illustration of this problem.

Comment: Without `#include <stdbool.h>` OPs code will not compile. So it is IMO copy-paste error https://godbolt.org/z/e4ET66

Comment: Tagged `[C]`. If compiled as fortran then will not compile as well. But how is it related to the tagged language?

Comment: Converting an unsigned integer type to a signed integer type outside the destination range is not undefined behavior. It is implementation-defined per C 2018 6.3.1.3 3.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: indeed the conversion has implementation defined behavior, the real issue is this: negating `(int32_t)value` has undefined behavior for `value == 0x80000000` unless type `int` is larger than `int32_t`. I amended the answer with a detailed explanation. Your answer addresses this issue in even more detail :)

Comment: The missing stdbool.h include was copy-paste error, fixed, thanks.